# NET SHARE just gives syntax "error"

Tags: powershell, share

As i am trying to set the following command in powershell:

```
NET SHARE ShareName=C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local /GRANT:UserName, READ
```

I get the following result:

```
NET : The syntax of this command is:
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The syntax of this command is::String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

NET SHARE
sharename
          sharename=drive:path [/GRANT:user,[READ | CHANGE | FULL]]
                               [/USERS:number | /UNLIMITED]
                               [/REMARK:"text"]
                               [/CACHE:Manual | Documents| Programs | BranchCache | None]
          sharename [/USERS:number | /UNLIMITED]
                    [/REMARK:"text"]
                    [/CACHE:Manual | Documents | Programs | BranchCache | None]
          {sharename | devicename | drive:path} /DELETE
          sharename \\computername /DELETE
```

I just can't find any syntax misstake.
I have already tried to put a "`" before the comma, that didn't help anything.

Any hints?

Comment: There should be no space between `UserName,` and `READ`. That should be enough in this case -- where it's not, remember that you can always use `--%` to force PowerShell to stop parsing and pass the command on as-is, so it works "just like" it would in `cmd`.

Comment: I get the same result, even without a space after that comma. I am not aware of --% - would i put that at the eol?

Comment: On my system, `NET SHARE ShareName=C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local /GRANT:UserName,READ` produces "System error 1332" due to the user name being invalid, not a syntax error. So does `NET SHARE --% ShareName=C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local /GRANT:UserName,READ`, which forces PowerShell not to parse (but that shouldn't really be the problem here).

Comment: That worked! Thanks very much for your quick help. You may want to put this as an actual answer..

Comment: I'd rather close as "simple typographical error", so I've voted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please run your Powershell ISE as Administrator.

keep your command inside $() and execute it as below example.

```
$(NET SHARE Neha=D:\Neha\Neha GRANT:Username,READ)
```

Neha was shared successfully.

Please try and let me know if you need any assistance.